# taking the input from a C# textBox ond putting it in an HTML TextBox on a web page

Tags: c#

So I have everything working at this point but one. I am getting an error under webBrowser1. I am not sure why please help. I know that I was aske if I am declering everything so I will edit the code below to show everything in the form.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

private void Submit_Click (object sender, EventArgs e)
{
using (WebBrowser browser = new WebBrowser())
        {
            browser.Url = new Uri("http://www.google.com");
            HtmlElement textBox = webBrowser1.Document.All["textbox1"];
            if (textBox1 != null)
            {
                textBox.InnerText = textBox1.Text;
            }

        }
}
```

Am i missing something to make this work right. Please advise.

Comment: So .. ? What's problem ?

Comment: It says it right there. I am trying to do this and it is not working. I mean how cleare do you need it. The guy below understod as he gave me an answer.

Comment: Dude - i gave answer. See my answer and comment over that.

Comment: was not you sir. was the ones that placed it on hold as unclear.

Comment: Can we do something about the nagative points on this. I mean evry one that answerd knew what i was asking.

Comment: +1 from me ......@Shawn

Comment: ya it is not you sir it is the ones that put it on hold, for what ever reason. You have been a big help up to this point and I than kyou for that.

Comment: the hold is because you don't say what the problem is.  you just say you are getting an error.  was it a compile error?  was it a runtime error, etc.  you seem to have put some of that info into comments in several answers, but that doesn't help those of us just looking at the question itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is with your assignment. If you want to take input from `textBox1` and assign it to html Textbox which is `textBox`, do it like as:

```
HtmlElement textBox = webBrowser1.Document.All["textbox1"];
if (textBox1 != null)
   {
      textBox.InnerText = textBox1.text;
   }
```

Comment: so i have your answer in my C# program, but I am getting the red lines all over. It is giving me an error for webBrowser1, InnerText, and text after textBox1. I am not sure why. can you help

Comment: May be you haven't set fields or added references properly as it's giving errors for variables.

Comment: would that be something that I have to set at the top of the whole program in the using section. and if so what would it be set as.

Comment: are you using VS 2012 ?

Comment: I am sir. I am just not sure what I am doing wrong

Comment: I posted every thing I have in the queston at the top sir. Please take a look and let me know what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Apologies but there's no namespace , no Form, no class, no ``Form_load`` ?

Comment: sorry about that was trying to take out the fluff.

Comment: You need to study webbrowser control of c#  - See this little guide. it will help you. Visit http://www.dotnetperls.com/webbrowser - I assume you didn't put `webbrowser`` object in form. See this answer as well.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5716662/how-to-use-the-net-webbrowser-object

Answer (score 0):

I guess one thing that it missing is .InnerText where you want to assign textBox content to textBox1.

```
if (textBox1 != null)
{
     textBox1.InnerText = textBox.InnerText;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your example it looks like you've got your goal flipped around. Shouldn't it look like this instead:

```
if(textBox != null)
{
    textBox.innerText = textBox1.Text;
}
```